# Can you separate schemas and objects with spaces and line feeds in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When writing a query, can you separate schemas and objects with spaces and line feeds?

Comment: Reminds me [Revenge: The SQL!](http://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event12/Revenge_The_SQL) similar ideas

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is valid T-SQL:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
sys
.
databases
d
WHERE
d
.
name
=
'tempdb';
```

As is this:

```
SELECT * FROM sys . databases d WHERE d . name = 'tempdb';
GO
```

And they both work fine.

[image]

Comment: Although the T-SQL parser is lax, I'd stick with the documented syntax where there are no spaces separating the schema and object name.

Comment: @DanGuzman sure, but notice this was a "can you" question, not a best practices opinion question. ;-)

Comment: One can get away with this and many other syntax mistakes. Fortunately for many, Microsoft goes through great lengths to preserve T-SQL parser bugs :-)